# PayPal order capture returns UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY TRANSACTION REFUSED

Tags: node.js, paypal

I am using PayPal hosted payment fields to attempt to accept cards on my app. On sandbox, everything works perfectly fine. I can create orders, capture them, and go about my day. This is not true for the production environment.

I am using this format to create the paypal order:

```
        let request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCreateRequest();
        request.prefer("return=representation");
        request.requestBody({
            intent: "CAPTURE",
            purchase_units: [{
                amount: {
                    currency_code: "USD"
                    value: "20.05"
                }
            }]
            application_context: {
                shipping_preference: "NO_SHIPPING"
            }
        });
```

Attempting to capture the order with any card I have results in this:

```
HttpError: {"name":"UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY","details":[{"issue":"TRANSACTION_REFUSED","description":"The request was refused"}],"message":"The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.","debug_id":"ee2fb8a7de388","links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#error-TRANSACTION_REFUSED","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}
```

I have tried this with about half a dozen credit/debit cards. They all get put down as an unprocessable entity. Originally I thought there must be something wrong with my business account itself. What I've found is that

1. Accepting payments in USD
2. Approved for advanced debit/credit card payments
3. Using the live credentials for the live app
4. Address of account is in US

I can't for the life of me figure out why the transaction is refusing. I checked with my bank and the funds are transferring out, and then back in after paypal refuses the transaction. Am I not providing sufficient information or something?

This is my capture for reference:

```
    var orderID = req.body.order;

    const request = new paypal.orders.OrdersCaptureRequest(orderID);
    request.requestBody({});

    try {
        const capture = await client.execute(request);

        console.log(capture);
        console.log(capture.result.payment_source)
        console.log(capture.result.purchase_units)

        //const captureID = capture.result.purchase_units[0].payments.captures[0].id;

        //console.log(captureID);

        //save captureID to database

        //await Capture.create({paypal_capture_id: captureID, order_id: capture.result.id})

        res.status(200).json(capture);

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        return res.status(400).json(err);
    }
```

Edit: Here is the billing address information:

```
var billingAddress = {

                streetAddress: billing_address_info.address.split(',')[0],
                // State
                region: billing_address_info.address.county,
                // City
                locality: billing_address_info.address.city,
                // Postal Code
                postalCode: billing_address_info.address.postal,
                // Country Code
                countryCodeAlpha2: lookup.byCountry(billing_address_info.country).iso2
            }
```

This logs as

```
{
    "streetAddress": "xxx",
    "extendedAddress": "xxx",
    "region": "xx",
    "locality": "xxxxx",
    "postalCode": "xxxxx",
    "countryCodeAlpha2": "xx"
 }
```

In my case the billing address is always some US validated address.

```
   if (
            Object.values(hostedFields.getState().fields).some(
                (field) => !field.isValid
            ) ||
            !cardHolderName
        ) {
            return alert(
                "The payment form is invalid, please check it before execute the payment"
            );
        }
    setPaying(true)
    hostedFields
        .submit({
            // The full name as shown in the card and billing address
            cardholderName: cardHolderName,
            billingAddress: billingAddress
        })
        .then(async (order) => {

            console.log(order)
            onApprove(order)
    
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            setPaying(false)
            console.log(err)
            console.log(err.response.data)
        })
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this Hosted Fields as in [Advanced Credit and Debit Cards](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/business/checkout/advanced-card-payments/integrate), or just the black Debit or Credit Card button? If the former, are you including a full billing address in card form submission before the capture? Show that part of your code.

TRANSACTION_REFUSED is a normal decline response by PayPal, and generally does not indicate an integration or technical problem, but rather that card being suspect in some way. If it's not the lack of a billing address w/Advanced fields, it may actually be the half dozen cards you're testing with are being refused for some reason, such as if they're *somehow* detected as being connected to the receiver account. Paying your own account in production is actually not permitted, though it's understandable why you'd want to verify it's working before putting it to a 'real customer' card.

Comment: I am using advanced debit and credit cards for the hosted fields. There is also a full billing address form as well yes. I will include the billing address portion in the original post. The cards I'm testing have the same address as the paypal business account itself. Do you think that presents a problem to paypal?

Comment: Yes, that is a problem. There should be zero connection to the receiver account.

Comment: Ok, I will have one of my business partners try their card and see if it works.

Comment: I have attempted to use one of my business partners cards with a different billing address as well of course. The cards still did not go through. Truly a conundrum.

Comment: In that case reach out to PayPal's support. Include the full `UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY` response message with its debug_id so they can do a deep dive as to the cause

Comment: Actually there might be one issue. I am getting the billing address information on the client side, but I am unaware if react-paypal-js (the way im submitting the fields) is actually sending it. On the docs they have the submission with cardHoldername, but not with billingAddress. It makes me wonder if the billing address information is even submitting. The curious part is I looked in their source code and they do have a PayPalHostedFieldBillingAddress prop. I will look into it.

Comment: Code looks fine; as long as the data is correct when passed to the `.submit` function, that's not the issue

Comment: Hi Preston, PayPal support got back to me and basically said the cards were being rejected because the transaction was "risky". Do you think there's a way to make the transaction less risky by putting information in the order creation?

Comment: You can try including line item in the v2/checkout/orders create request, as per the example in bullet #6 of 'add and modify the code' in this Checkout integration guide https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/standard/integrate/ .. but it would seem more likely to be something about the business account processing the payment. Try with a different one.